# How to change the start simulation time for smoke in Blender

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am trying to make a smokey text with smoke simulation. I am using particles systems to emit the smoke. I want my text to appear gradually for the first 30 frames and then the smoke simulation has to start. I adjusted the start(0) and end frames (30th frame) in Emission parameter settings  for particles systems to create a gradually appearing effect. But the issue is simulation is already getting started from first frame, so the text is not readable. Any methods to keep the text steady (unaffected by simulation for first few frames) and then start the simulation?

Thank You

Comment: If you're emitting particles from 0 to 30 frames and the smoke will be generated by those particles, of course the smoke rises from the beginning on. If you want smoke from particles beginning at frame 30, then the particles' **start** frame has to be 30, not the end frame. If this still produces smoke from the beginning, make sure the smoke's _Flow Source_ is set to _Particle System_, not _Mesh_.

Comment: if i set start frame to 30, the title wont be able to see in the first 30 frames.

Comment: Does your text consist of particles or why won't the text be visible in the first 30 frames? If so, I think your question is missing some information to solve the problem.

Comment: The text has particle system. But when i change start frame to 30, the particles will only start to emit from 30th frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question I guess it's lacking some important information on how you've set up the text and the particles.

Anyway, if you want to keyframe the smoke emission with an *Inflow* smoke emitter there are different ways depending on the smoke settings, here are some examples.

If your *Flow* object is set to *Flow Source* > *Mesh*, smoke can be controlled by animating the following values:

1. the *Use Flow* checkbox
2. the value for *Density*
3. the values for *Surface Emission* and/or *Volume Emission*

If your *Flow* object is set to *Flow Source* > *Particle System*, smoke can be controlled by animating these values:

1. the value for *Density*
2. the *Frame Start* and *End* of the *Particle Emitter*

The *Use Flow* checkbox unfortunately has no effect on the particle smoke (at least not in my Blender version). Since your comment implies you want smoke from particles and cannot use the start/end frame method, the *Density* value seems to be your only option.

[image: smoke flow settings]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments