# How do I emit smoke at a specific frame?

Tags: mantaflow

[image]

I'd like to emit smoke from this object at a specific frame. Before that frame, I'd like there to be absolutely zero smoke visible. I've tried animating the "Use Flow", density, surface emission, initial velocity, but no matter what I do, there will always be this smoke that just stays there until it shoots out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the start simulation time for smoke in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242261/how-to-change-the-start-simulation-time-for-smoke-in-blender)

Comment: no but thank you for offering the help, i'll repost this question in a bit

Answer (score 0):

3 things you have to keep in mind:

1. keyframe "use flow" unchecked 1 keyframe before it should start
2. keyframe "use flow" checked at keyframe where it should start
3. change any settings on the domain that it takes effect (or delete bake)

Comment: Already did those, the smoke still remains. I think i'll rephrase and repost this question

Comment: this works...then please provide your blend file. Maybe you have another domain/emission object?